# Using System.Web.Security in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt the cookie value but I couldn't.

This is my code

```
var cookieText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Text for Cookie");
var encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(MachineKey.Protect(cookieText, "ProtectCookie"));
```

For this, I have to reference:

```
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
```

but the `using System.Security;` does not work in ASP.NET Core 6.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image: here I catch the error]

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. The namespace you try to use was for WebForms , replaced by ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET MVC. 2FA through SMS verification was [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity) and [while it's still there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1) it's safer to use [TOTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-1.1)

Comment: Instead of trying to make WebForms work in ASP.NET Core, try to find and use the equivalent 2FA feature in ASP.NET Core. There's no longer any need for manual encryption. [There are many authentication schemes, including cookie authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Data Protection Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It supports your scenario and is available in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful to me,  now how can I  decrypt cookies in HTML Layout? I want to use this cookie for the User Name client.